# Style an Outlook Calander embeded in a html Website

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, outlook-addin

I have the following Problem:

I embeded an Outlook Calendar to my Website using an iFrame and everything looks and works as intended.
But I want to style the Calender.
How can I do so?

I want the Calander to look way simpler and remove some stuff and also I want that it only shows the current day, not the full month.

```
<iframe src="https://outlook.live.com/owa/calendar/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/0c153dcb-2f12-47dd-8430-827d15e3a888/cid-24879FF544F39772/index.html" scrolling="no" width="1100" height="700" frameboarder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the contents of an iframe via css.

Comment: Is there any possibility to give it parameters or do I have to accept the default style?

Comment: Or can I put the Calander in a div or something else where I can style it?

Comment: You have to accept the default styles. Only possiblity to get a styled calender would be to use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations) and a JavaScript-Calender like https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Could you tell me more about how I can use fullCalender to display an Outlook Calander on my Website or link me a Tutorial?

Comment: Sorry. You'll need to read the docs. And it's going to be way more complicated than an simple iframe-embed.